# how to set rows and column in bootstrap different orders depending on size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to order some objects in different web browsers size
I've learned from bootstrap how to reorder with col-xx-push or col-xx-pull.

But I'm unable to replicate this order which I left in a picture. I'd appreciate help please, as I've tried it for a while and can't seem to get it right.

[image: movil view]

[image: website view]

I've got this until now

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="a col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">A</div>
 <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">B</div>
 <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">C</div>
 <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12">D</div>
</div>
```

I'm missing to organize it in xs to 4 rows in order:
C 
D
B
A

Comment: How about generating the (A) content twice. Sometimes it is shown on the narrow screen, sometimes on the wide

Comment: could you develop that example please, I don't get it well what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach is to generate columns A and B columns twice as below. Then show/hide the columns A and B using bootstrap responsive utilities like hidden-xs and visible-xs-*.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="a col-md-6 hidden-xs col-xs-push-12">A</div>
    <div class=" col-md-6 hidden-xs col-xs-pull-12">B</div>
    <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">C</div>
    <div class=" col-md-6 col-xs-12">D</div>
    <div class="visible-xs-12">B</div>
    <div class="visible-xs-12">A</div>
</div>
```

More info on using responsive utilities is here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: nice example! you were only missing hidden-md in the last two rows to make it just how I wanted. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

push and pull used for rearranging column, not row.
Example if you have

```
c
d
b
a
```

on mobile and you want

```
abcd
```

on desktop, you rearrange it using push and pull. In your case, i think it's called visible and unvisible on different size. Here you do it. First create two same size column. Left for pic, right etc. (md)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        pic(A)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        B
        C
        D
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, you begin to design responsive using push and pull because on mobile you want pic on bottom. To do this, it's better to start over from mobile so you edit it to become like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        B
        C
        D
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        pic(A)
    </div>
</div>
```

And add push and pull. Because if you didn't push and pull, on pc, pic will be on the right, and etc on the left.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        B
        C
        D
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        pic(A)
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok, now using visible and hidden to rearrange the row on mobile. To do this, we have to create each div.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <div class="hidden-md">
            B
        </div>
        C
        D
        <div class="visible-md-12">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        pic(A)
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it help you learn.

Reading source : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: One question, if I didn't have bootstrap, how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Hem, let see. You can download bootstrap (obviously) or you can include it in your html file like bootstrap example on w3school :D

Comment: ahh No haha, my boss told me I can't use bootstrap :/